# Clarification for a statment from ArXiv:1812.07690 "Asymptotics of Nahm sums at roots of unity"

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics

This is a cross-post of the same [math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954395/clarification-for-a-statment-from-arxiv1812-07690-asymptotics-of-nahm-sums-at) to MO, thinking that is better suited here.

My question is about Lemma 2.1 from the [ArXiv:1812.07690](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07690) by D. Zagier and S. Garoufalidis which concerns q-pochhammer symbol $(z; q)_{\infty} = \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - z \cdot q^k \right)$, an entire function of $z$ for all complex $q$ such that $\left\vert q \right\vert < 1$.

Consider $q$ to be near the root of unity: $q = \zeta \exp\left(-\epsilon/m\right)$, where $\zeta$ is the $m$-th primitive root of unity, $\epsilon$ is small, and $z = q \ w \ \exp\left( -\nu \epsilon/m\right)$ for a complex $\nu$, such that $\nu \ \epsilon = \mathcal{o}(1)$ the lemma 2.1 states

$$\begin{align}
-\log\left(q\ w \ e^{-\nu \ \epsilon/m}; q\right)_{\infty} &= \left.- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(1- q^n w e^{-\nu \epsilon/m}\right) \right|_{\mathrm{using}\ \ -\log(1-u) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k} }\\ &= \left. \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n k} w^k e^{-\nu k \epsilon/m} \right|_{\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n k} = \sum_{t=1}^{m} \sum_{s=0}^\infty q^{t k} q^{m k s} = \sum_{t=1}^m \frac{q^{t k}}{1-q^{m k}} }  \\ &= \left.\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sum_{t=1}^{m}  \left(\zeta^t w\right)^k \frac{e^{-(\nu +t) \epsilon\ k/m} }{1 - e^{- \epsilon \ k}}\right\vert_{\frac{e^{-(\nu +t) \epsilon\ k/m} }{1 - e^{- \epsilon \ k}}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{ \left(k \epsilon\right)^{r-1}}{r!} B_{r}\left(1-\frac{\nu+t}{m}\right) } \\
 &= \left.\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^{r-1}}{r!} \sum_{t=1}^m B_{r}\left(1-\frac{\nu+t}{m}\right) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\zeta^t w\right)^k}{k} k^{r-1} \right\vert_{ \mathrm{Li}_{s}(w) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}} \\
 &= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^{r-1}}{r!} \sum_{t=1}^m B_{r}\left(1-\frac{\nu+t}{m}\right)  \mathrm{Li}_{2-r}\left(\zeta^t w\right)
\end{align}
$$

This sequence clearly demonstrates that the expansion is $\mathbb{C}[\nu][[\epsilon]]$, i.e. polynomial in $\nu$ and containing some negative powers of $\epsilon$.

In addition to this, the lemma 2.1 states $\psi_{w, \zeta}\left(\nu,\epsilon\right)$ defined as
$$
   \psi_{w, \zeta}\left(\nu,\epsilon\right) \left.=\right._{\mathrm{def}} \sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^{r-1}}{r!} \sum_{t=1}^m B_{r}\left(1-\frac{\nu+t}{m}\right)  \mathrm{Li}_{2-r}\left(\zeta^t w\right)
$$
has an explicit asymptotic expansion in $\mathbb{C}[\nu \epsilon^{2/3}][[ \epsilon^{1/3} ]] \subset \mathbb{C}[\nu][[\epsilon]]$ as $\epsilon \searrow 0$.  I fail to see why this claim might be true, and how one would derive this explicit asymptotic expansion.

I am hoping to get help with that here.

Comment: Interesting, the Bernoulli polynomials and the polylog, which are being convolved here, are both  particular manifestations of the Hurwitz zeta function on which there is much literature. Perhaps googling "convolution Hurwtiz zeta function" might be productive. Also, the Lerch zeta function is a generalization.